# Expose tunnel application, not able to run on Mac

Tags: php, zshrc

Not able to run expose on mac tried the Linux solution but no success.

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

and adding

> export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"

with zshrc

> 

```
> > Anurag@Anurags-MacBook-Pro-523 ~ % composer global require beyondcode/expose                                 Changed current
> directory to /Users/Anurag/.composer Using version ^1.3 for
> beyondcode/expose ./composer.json has been updated Loading composer
> repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including
> require-dev) Nothing to install or update Generating autoload files
> Anurag@Anurags-MacBook-Pro-523 ~ % expose token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx      
> zsh: command not found: expose
```

[image]

Comment: How is this related to Composer? As far as I see, installing that package works fine, so what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: I tried adding the path to the .zshrc                                     
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"          still the terminal shows                                                         
zsh: command not found: expose

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked whether `PATH` contains the path yet? Whether `$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin` contains the `expose` application?

Comment: No, the PATH doesn't contain the expose application